# CSS for printing a webpage

Tags: html, css, printing

I have this HTML structure:

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class='main container'>
    <div class='sidebar'></div>
    <div class='content'>
      <table id='sortthis'></table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

but when I try to print preview, the content is rendered a bit towards the right(which is its location on the actual page).

How do I center this content? OR is this a matter of some invisible elements occupying space within the page? I'm pretty sure I do not have those.

I've set the displayed element to max width of 215.9mm (@page size: legal; margin: 12.7mm;)

EDIT:

```
  @media print
    {
    body  * {margin:0; padding:0}
    body, #sortthis {border:1px solid #000;}    
    body header, body footer {display:none;}
    div.main.container div.sidebar {display:none;}
    div.main.container div.content > :not(#sortthis) {display:none;}
    div.main.container div.content > #sortthis {color:#000;}
    #sortthis tbody tr > td.exclude, #sortthis thead tr > th.exclude {display:none;}
    #sortthis {margin:0 auto, padding:0; width:215.9mm;}
    }

  @page {
    size: letter portrait;
    margin: 12.7mm;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set up a print stylesheet so that you can alter the layout without affecting the main frontend styles.

For example:

```
@media print {
   …
}
```

Comment: I already did, and its stil somehow to right of the print page. please review my css of it above.